# Django: Create new model attributes from current model variables

Tags: django, django-models

As I am new to Django I am practicing building a money-saving app. In the app, I want to create model attributes from my current model input. The user-created model fields look like this:

```
class Items(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, default='Enter name')
    item_category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    item_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=False)
    item_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    item_end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    item_purchase_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
    item_rest_value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Using four of these fields (item_start_date, item_end_date, item_purchase_price, item_rest_value) I want to calculate several things.

- Save goal (purchase price - rest value)
- Save period in days (end date - start date)
- Days passed (end_date - current_date)

I tried this doing the below:

```
def __init__(self, item_name, item_start_date, item_end_date, item_purchase_price, item_rest_value):
    self.item_name = item_name
    self.item_start_date = item_start_date
    self.item_end_date = item_end_date
    self.item_purchase_price = item_purchase_price
    self.item_rest_value = item_rest_value

def get_saving_goal(self, item_purchase_price, item_rest_value):
    return self.item_purchase_price - self.item_rest_value

def get_date_delta(self, item_end_date, item_start_date):
    return self.item_end_date - self.item_start_date

def get_days_passed(self, ):
    from datetime import date
    today = date.today()
    return today - self.item_start_date  ## probably will need something like a datediff function
```

**Question 1:** However, when I add these methods below the model fields, it shows this error. How do I solve this?

> **init**() takes 6 positional arguments but 10 were given

**Question 2:** Beside the error, I am wondering how I can use these methods as a field. In other words, how can I use the method's outcomes in the same way as the model fields?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it like this (overwriting the `save()` function):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.item_saving_goal = self.item_purchase_price - self.item_rest_value
    self.item_date_delta = (self.item_end_date.year - self.item_start_date.year) * 12 + ( self.item_end_date.month - self.item_start_date.month )
    self.item_days_passed = (date.today().year - self.item_start_date.year) * 12 + ( date.today().month - self.item_start_date.month )
    self.item_currently_saved = self.item_saving_goal * (self.item_days_passed / self.item_date_delta )
    self.item_percentage_saved = self.item_currently_saved / self.item_saving_goal * 100
    self.item_monthly_saving = self.item_saving_goal / self.item_date_delta
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).